# How to compare current value with old value in TextWatcher?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I'm rendering the values from my database and placing those values in respective EditText field, so generally allowing the users to modify their save data.

I have a SAVE button on my page, where by default disabled. It should be enabled only when the EditText fields are really modified.

When comparing with the Database value,

1. If the edit text value is changed  - modified
2. If the EditText Value is edited but not changed (user may copy paste the same value)- not modified.

Here is my code,

```
EditText text1  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
EditText text2  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
EditText text3  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);
EditText text4  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text4);
EditText text5  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text5);

ArrayList<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList();
editTextList.add(text1);
editTextList.add(text2);
editTextList.add(text3);
editTextList.add(text4);
editTextList.add(text5);

for(EditText e : editTextList)
  e.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int 
after) {}
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int 
count) {}
};
```

Is there any way to compare the database value with current given value in EditText?

NOTE:

Since the TextWatcher function is common to all EditText, I want to do the comparison common.

Answer (score 0):

you have to control it by yourself with a global variable. or reactive object or use databinding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: Global variable example: public Activity extends AppCompactActivity{}